# Can I write to a file through the Logitech Lua api?

Tags: c#, lua, sdk, macros, logitech

The reason I want to do this is because I am trying to light a single key through a script. I want to invoke the script through **Logitech lua api**. the functionality will act as a feedback response.
fx I have create a macro for the G1 button and I want to light that specific button when the macro is active and turn it off when it isn't.
My solution is that I have created a C# script that repeatedly looks in a text file. If the text file has written "on" in it, it turns on the LED etc.
now I just need a way to update the text file through the logitech Lua API.
but it does not seem as I am allowed to write to a file.

I have tried with the following code to write to the text file:

```lua
file = io.open("D:\\creative\\programming\\C#\\logi\\test.txt", "w")
file:write("on")
file:close()
```

but without any luck as I get the error message:

> [string "LuaVM"]:35: attempt to index a nil value (global 'io') Line
> Number:1

------------------------- extra to explain comment ----------------------------

let say that I have actions inside applications in parenthesis and actions without effect in italic:
assume it is off to begin: the "**->**"  acts as a g1 press and shows the sate of the toggle after:

-> on -> off

-> (on) -> (*on*) -> on ========>   -> on -> off -> on

because the g1 presses while the loop is running and the application window is focused are queued and will only take effect while outside the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`io` library is absent, so you can not write to a file from Lua code.
But you can execute external program (for example, any exe-file) by creating a macro (of type "shortcut") and invoking it with `PlayMacro(macro_name)` from Lua code.
Just write the external program in C#.

Comment: Yea, that was also what i ended up doing. Do you know if there a way to execute blocks of code i parallel or have coroutines. I dont know if that will solve my current issue. The problem i have now is whenever i run my makro inside an application it allows me to start the makro, but not to stop it to stop the running makro i have to unfocus the application otherwise the console does not seem the register mouse/key events

Comment: If an application is focused i can start the macro, but any event while the window is focused and the macro is running, will just be queued untill i unfocus it, and trigger a new event. Which means i am only able to stop the macro outside the application

Comment: I don't understand what means "to stop the macro".  Your macro is very fast - start external windowless exe-file (which modifies the file and immediately exits).  No focus / unfocus happens.

Comment: `i have to unfocus the application otherwise the console does not seem the register mouse/key events` LGS switches profiles automatically depending on exe file which is currently foreground.  You can write multiple exe files in single LGS profile, so that switching between these exe files does not change LGS profile.

Comment: i'm not sure how else to explain it. So I have a toggle function on my G1 key, the function is a loop that will repeat itself until the g1 key is pressed again. if I ON-toggle it while being on the desktop screen I can easily OFF-toggle it, but if I ON-toggle it inside an application it will start the loop but I am not able to OFF-toggle it (break the loop) if I do that, it will basically queue the input action and awake it whenever I do another action outside the application but then it will essentially ON-toggle again because it adds on a new action with the already queued.

Comment: I have updated the question above to try to give an example

Comment: also this cannot be due to profile switching as i do not have a profile associated with the exe-file, besides the application is not even being picked up by logitech G hub

Comment: What "application" you are talking about?  Is it your own written on C# application or some other application (such as a game or Microsoft Word)?  How do you start the application (from GHub macro or not from GHub)? GHub profile can be linked to ANY application(s) on your PC.

Comment: I understood nothing from the update of the question.

Comment: If we have problem with understanding when writing words, maybe you can create a video (from your screen) explaining the problem?

Comment: `i do not have a profile associated with the exe-file` - in this case GHub switches from the current profile to the "default" profile.

Comment: I have tried to show it with a video: https://www.veed.io/view/02d4b997-2869-450d-9292-85dc294f135e?sharingWidget=true&panel=share

Comment: The profile switches when you unfocus game and focus GHub window.  This means Lua script from the game profile stops and "default" profile Lua scripts starts.  The game script logic fails, of course.